# Why can I not install gems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

As of today I cannot install any gems.  AFAIK nothing has changed.

On install I get the following:

```
$ ~/ gem install sinatra
WARNING:  Error fetching data: hostname does not match the server certificate (https://gemcutter.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
WARNING:  Error fetching data: hostname does not match the server certificate (https://gemcutter.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'sinatra' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: sinatra
```

Any ideas? (This is on a Mac)

Comment: Can you supply more info? You're obviously in a linux/unix system, but which distro/system, which ruby version you use (rvm, rbenv, system-ruby). Do you use custom DNS (i.e. openDNS/GoogleDNS or ISP dns?). Answer those first... I just installed mechanize on a local system so the gem server works fine.

Comment: Added that I'm on a Mac.  Nothing is any different that the working state that it was last week, that I know of.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, I think it could be something with the RubyGems issue that's been going on as of lately.

Comment: The way i fixed this is opening up .gemrc and under sources removing the line

    - http://gemcutter.org

Comment: Yes, removing gemcutter from the sources fixed this.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure as to why but by editing my `~/.gemrc` and removing all sources bar `rubygems.org`, the problem went away.

Comment: I had the same problem, and this solution worked to me as well!